# How to load only part of the dictionary in AEM 6.0?

Tags: internationalization, aem

I am using AEM6.0 SP2. On author, the editor interface for french site shows in french language; though my preferences is set to English. Author dialog labels/texts are shown in french translation. This happens to my site only and does not happen in Geometrixx. 
For example cancel inheritance dialog shows like this [image: frenchsitedialog]

But same dialog for a Geometrixx site shows in English. I compared Geometrixx site with mine and couldnt find any significant difference.

Further digging, I am seeing /libs/cq/i18n/dict.en_us.json returns only custom translation, but /libs/cq/i18n/dict.fr_ca.json in additional to our custom translation returns also AEM OOTB translations. The custom translations are placed properly at /apps/myapp/i18n. org.apache.sling.i18n jar version is 2.2.8.

How to render author dialog in preference language only and not site language?

Answer (score 0):

The dictionaries are meant to match keys to the language specific text and fall back to the key if a translation for the specified language doesn't exist.  Adobe implements this by making the key English and providing an English dictionary.  This is why you don't see OOTB English translations for http://localhost:4502/libs/cq/i18n/dict.en_us.json. Is it possible that you're keys are the French text and it's falling back to the key?

Comment: No. My dictionary definition is right. My question is, why is the cq:dialog and cq:widgets picking url language and NOT preference language. In case of Geometrixx pages it renders i18n texts from preference language. Only my application pages behave this way. Couldnt figure out what mistake I am doing.